# Create 2 tabar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to create an application like below picture

[image]

my Home tab has these 3 top tab bar's(Number, Address, Emails) with Segment Control

My question is what is the best way for calling these 3parts

One Way:
in UIViewController having UIView in center and create one UItableView for each tabs

Second Way:

having one UITableView in first page, and create custom row for each tabs

I appreciated if you can give me some hints or better way

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or you can create your own Container View Controller, and push your controllers to the container view. So all your states (table view) will be encapsulated in different classes (UIViewController), see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: I would probably have one tableView, 3 different containing numbers in one, addresses in other one, and emails in the next one. When the segmented control changes, I will display the proper data in the same table except change the source of the array to one of the following array.

Comment: Also you can create 3 different classes for every different state that conforms to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate prtocols, change that objects for you tabgle view. and call [tableView reloadData]

Answer (score 1):

A third way is to make the contents of the window a container view that includes another view controller using an embed segue. Then you could swap out the contents of your window based on the segment the user selects.

Which approach is best depends on the specifics of your app. Is the data you're presenting different enough that it warrants using a different view controller for each set of data, or could you write a single view controller that could display all 3 types of data?

If you simply have 3 different cell types you could use a single table view and just reload the table view with different types of cells, populated with different data, depending on which segment the user selects in your top segmented control.

Comment: "Which approach is best depends on the specifics of your app" I think that encapsulating every state in new class is more good for code supporting, so even if now thay really similar, who knows what may come to mind to the customer or designer tomorrow?